# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django

I’m using Django 1.10 with Python 2.7. I have a problem running a Python script that uses Django models.

```
 $ python contentui_app/content-util.py --sig

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "contentui_app/content-util.py", line 9, in <module>
        from models import *
      File "/var/django-project/contentui/contentui_app/models.py", line 12, in <module>
        class AuthGroup(models.Model):
      File "/var/django-project/contentui/contentui_app/models.py", line 13, in AuthGroup
        name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1043, in __init__
        super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
        self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
        % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

#

this is the code

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
from optparse import OptionParser
from pprint import pprint
import sys, os, hashlib, re, datetime, inspect, time, string, django
sys.path.append("/var/alertlogic/django-project/contentui")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "contentui.settings")
django.setup()

from contentui_app.models import *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused when you don’t initialize Django. Try running this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from contentui import settings
settings.configure(settings)
```

before the rest of your code.

Comment: good thanks but this is the new error. RuntimeError: Model class models.AuthGroup doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: What’s this print? `python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"])'`?

Comment: This                                                                                                           python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"])'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'

Comment: Does your `settings.py` have `contentui_app` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Yes
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'contentui_app',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'debug_toolbar'
]

Comment: Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39150159/edit) your post post the code of the `content-util.py` script?

Comment: @PabloAndresSantamariaZarate See edit. Does this work?

Comment: ok this is part of the code from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
from optparse import OptionParser
from pprint import pprint
import sys, os, hashlib, re, datetime, inspect, time, string, django
sys.path.append("/var/alertlogic/django-project/contentui")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "contentui.settings")
django.setup()

from contentui_app.models import *

def options():
    'Parse command line options with optparse.'

    global options,args,debug

Comment: can you edit into your question? [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39150159/edit)? It’s **far** easier to read that way.

Comment: @ansanta Does either `from . import settings` or `import settings` work?

Comment: Thanks for your help yes work but with code from django.conf import settings
import settings
from optparse import OptionParser
from pprint import pprint
import string, sys, django, os.path, hashlib, re, datetime, inspect
from content_app.models import *